# MySQL difficulties with AS combined with HAVING

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have an AS-related MySQL question, specifically when combined with HAVING:

This **does** work (mind the "(250) AS", second line):

```
SELECT A.uid, A.name, A.height, A.width,
(250) AS squaresize
FROM tx_fach_domain_model_professional A,
tx_fach_domain_model_category B,
tx_fach_professional_category_mm MM
WHERE MM.uid_local = A.uid and
MM.uid_foreign = 2
HAVING squaresize > 20
ORDER BY squaresize LIMIT 0 , 4;
```

This does **NOT** work:

```
SELECT A.uid, A.name, A.height, A.width,
(A.height * A.width) AS squaresize
FROM tx_fach_domain_model_professional A,
tx_fach_domain_model_category B,
tx_fach_professional_category_mm MM
WHERE MM.uid_local = A.uid and
MM.uid_foreign = 2
HAVING squaresize > 20
ORDER BY squaresize LIMIT 0 , 4;
```

The strange thing is that it doesn't give me any errors but that it simply returns 4 of the very same rows/records, instead of 4 different ones.

Pretty clueless here..

Above is the simplified version of my real problem.. Where I have (200) in my example above, I'm actually trying to measure the **distance** value between longitude and latitude values:

```
SELECT A.uid, A.name, A.latitute, A.longitute,
( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(52.52000659999999) ) 
* cos( radians( A.latitute ) ) * cos( radians( A.longitute ) - 
radians(13.404953999999975) ) + sin ( radians(52.52000659999999) ) * sin( 
radians( A.latitute ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM tx_fach_domain_model_professional A, 
tx_fach_domain_model_category B, 
tx_fach_professional_category_mm MM WHERE MM.uid_local = A.uid and 
MM.uid_foreign = 2 HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 4;
```

Now this works as long as I don't use HAVING distance < 20 ORDER BY distance .. But as soon as I use these, I get the 4 very same results, instead of the expected 4 **different** results.

But, in my simplified example, I'm having the exact same issue.

**[SOLUTION]** This is what did the trick and provided the functionallity what I need - as proposed by @AsConfused:

```
SELECT A.uid, A.name, A.latitute, A.longitute,
( 6371 * acos ( cos ( radians(52.52000659999999) )
* cos( radians( A.latitute ) ) * cos( radians( A.longitute ) 
radians(13.404953999999975) ) + sin ( radians(52.52000659999999) ) *
sin(radians( A.latitute ) ) ) ) AS distance
FROM tx_fach_domain_model_professional A JOIN
tx_fach_professional_category_mm MM
on MM.uid_local = A.uid and MM.uid_foreign = 2
HAVING distance < 20
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 4;
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: use explicit join and do not select from table1,table2...

Comment: HAVING is intended for aggregate function conditions. Use together with GROUP BY.

Comment: Why don't you just do `WHERE (A.height * A.width) > 20` ?

Comment: U aren't even using _category B

Comment: `HAVING A.height * A.width > 20`

Comment: Thanks for your comments :-) Actually, I used (200) as a simplified demonstration of my problem. Actually I'm doing some distance calculations on that location. Please see the additional information I've added to the post.

Comment: Still @Daan has got a point ...

Comment: Using WHERE (A.height * A.width) > 20 actually works, BUT, will not result in me having the distance as a field I can use, which I need.

Comment: For the record i never mentioned using the HAVING. Improper use. Use WHERE  ;). Please read again what @jarlh said. U are doing calcs not aggregates (such as sum count max etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT A.uid, A.name, A.height, A.width
FROM tx_fach_domain_model_professional A
Join tx_fach_professional_category_mm MM
on MM.uid_local = A.uid and
MM.uid_foreign = 2
LIMIT 0 , 4;
```

Note that squaresize is hard coded and useless in your top chunk that works as u say. The 250 is known by the front-end

Comment: Ok saw your update to question. Your squaresize can be in where clause. Hope this stub helps some

Comment: Actually I need the distance, that's my ultimate goal. If I place the formula to calculate the distance into the where clause I do not have the distance value available in the end..

Comment: I know. Like i said i saw your updated question. Keep the variable

Comment: This actually helped me solved it :-)

I'll update the question with the answer.

Cool, thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: My pleasure. If u re-use that arc-cosine/cosine calc in a lot of queries, create a function passing in lat,longitude and use that fcn in your select